Checking when a request made by window.open() finished
I have a backend URL which returns a download response to download a PDF file. The URL is called by clicking a button which then uses window.open() to fetch the URL:
let downloadUrl = '/download-pdf';
window.open(
  `${downloadUrl}`,
  '_self'
);

I want to add a loading animation to the download button after the user clicks it, so I need to know when the response finished
Is it even possible to track it when using window.open()? If so, how?
And if not - is there another way I can emulate this window.open() and be able to track the response?

I don't think this is possible with the window.open method. Best if you download it in the same page, then you can track.

You can window.open a page with the PDF contained in an iframe with the load event handler

As long as the PDF URL is same-origin, you should be able to simply attach a load event handler to the new window? window.open(...).onload = function() { ... }

window.open in _self, if it works, would likely clear any script/html in the window, and therefore also your spinner.
